# Microsoft Query - UNION ALL

Tags: sql, microsoft-query

I am using Microsoft Query to summarize Excel table like below.

Here Status "W" denotes "Work", "AL" Denotes "Annual Leave" and "CL" Denotes "Casual Leave". Each employee has different status for each day (for 365 days).

```
| Employee_ID | 1-Jan |2-Jan|3-Jan|4-Jan|......|31-Dec|
| --------    | ----- |-----|-----|-----|......|------|
| John        | W     |W    |W    |W    |......|CL    |
| Paul        | W     |AL   |AL   |AL   |......|W     |
```

I was trying to aggregate the Status for each month by UNPIVOTING each Day column( i.e 1-Jan, 2-Jan etc..) by using below SQL query

```
SELECT   
  Timesheet.Status,
  COUNT(Timesheet.Status) 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      `Working$`.Emp_No, 
      '1-Jan' AS Trn_Date, 
      `Working$`.`1-Jan` AS Status 
    FROM 
      `Working$` `Working$` 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
      `Working$`.Emp_No, 
      '2-Jan' AS Trn_Date, 
      `Working$`.`2-Jan` AS Status 
    FROM 
      `Working$` `Working$` 
    )AS Timesheet
WHERE RIGHT(Timesheet.Trn_Date,3) = ?
GROUP BY Timesheet.Status
```

I have set a parameter to filter the Status Aggregation by month. The above query works fine until 49 "UNION ALL" and then Excel ODBC Driver throws following error
"[MICROSOFT][ODBC EXCEL DRIVER]QUERY IS TOO COMPLEX"

| Status | EXPR1001 |
| --- | --- |
| W | 30 |
| CL | 4 |
| AL | 7 |

How to overcome this issue. Thanks

Comment: Which "MIcrosoft Query" are you referring to? (Not the 16-bit era one, I hope?)

Comment: Why are you using backticks?

Comment: @Dai Microsoft Query (Predecessor to Power Query) Backticks can be omitted. Standard way of Microsoft Query

Comment: So why not use PowerQuery then?

Comment: @Dai
1. Power query is relatively slow when it comes to large data set
2. Parameterized Query is realtime while using Microsoft query
3. SQL in my opinion is relatively easy as compared to M Query